# Trying to create glfw application with batch file

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, glfw

I'm trying to create a glfw application on windows 10 using VC++ 2017 compiler. I built the glfw library using this compiler but when trying to run it with my batch file I keep getting 'unresolved external symbol' errors within the glfw3.lib file. I believe the issue lies within my batch file since I can use that same .lib file and everything within visual studio 2017, and everything will build fine. Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off

if not defined DevEnvDir ( call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" )

chdir /D w:\
cd memo 

set CommonCompilerFlags=-MT -Gm- -MP -Z7 -nologo -Oi -Od -WX -W3 -GR -EHa- -wd4505
set CommonLinkerFlags=-subsystem:windows -machine:x64 -incremental:no -nologo -opt:ref

set IncludePaths=-I "w:/memo/third_party/glfw3.2.1/include"
set LibraryPaths=/LIBPATH:"w:/memo/third_party/glfw3.2.1/lib/vc2017x64"
set Libraries="user32.lib" "OpenGL32.lib" "Gdi32.lib" "glfw3-debug.lib"

IF NOT EXIST build mkdir build
pushd build

cl /c w:\memo\source\noteapp_win64.cpp %CommonCompilerFlags% %IncludePaths%
link w:\memo\build\noteapp_win64.obj %CommonLinkerFlags% %LibraryPaths% %Libraries%  

popd
```

Is there anything wrong here? I'm still pretty new to batch files.

UPDATE:

I was able to get my unresolved symbols down a bit by adding a couple additional import libraries to my build file - "Shell32.lib" - however not all the way there yet. These linker errors still remain:

```
glfw3-debug.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(egl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
glfw3-debug.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wassert
glfw3-debug.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wassert
glfw3-debug.lib(egl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wassert
glfw3-debug.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wassert
glfw3-debug.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wassert
glfw3-debug.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wassert
glfw3-debug.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wassert
glfw3-debug.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf referenced in function _vsscanf_l
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_wcscpy referenced in function createMonitor
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetMonitors
glfw3-debug.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__strdup referenced in function _glfwAllocMonitor
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strdup
glfw3-debug.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strdup
LIBCMT.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
noteapp_win64.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're building a Release configuration (`-MT`) program but linking against a Debug configuration .lib file. That might be your problem, normally they should match.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still no change. Tried removing -MT altogether and also tried using -MTd instead. Neither worked. I know it has to be something like this though given my paths are correct and it was able to build correctly in visual studio.

Comment: You seem to be missing the CRT libraries.

Comment: Ya your right. But I thought those libraries were linked implicitly?